# PHP - easy mysql select from database

Tags: php, mysql

i am using this code to make easy search in database based on result from FORM

```
class Data {
     public $vin = null;

     public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
         if( isset( $data['vin'] ) ) $this->vin = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['vin'] ) );
     }

     public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
        $this->__construct( $params ); 
     }

     public function fetchByVin() {
         $success = false;
         try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_vin WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 1";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();


            if( $valid ) {
                $success = true;
            }
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<th>Progress</th>";
                echo "<th>Claim number</th>";
                echo "<th>Make</th>";
                echo "<th>Status</th>";
                echo "<th>View</th>";
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>24</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['claim_number']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['licence']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['vin']."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href=\"detail.php?id=".$row["id"]."&action=detail\">detail</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                     } 
                }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                $e->getMessage();
                }
                echo "</table>"; 
             return $success;
         }
```

My form looks like:

```
   <form method="post" action="">
        <p class="input_description">
        Search by VIN
        </p>
        <p class="input_field"> 
        <input type="text"  maxlength="30" required autofocus name="vin">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="send">
        </div>
        </form>
<?php
    $data = new Data;
    $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

    if( $usr->fetchByVin() ) {
        echo "Prebehne presmerovanie....";    
    } else {
        echo "VIN nebolo nájdene";    
    }
}
    }
    else {
    echo "Prosím prihláste sa <a href='login.php'> TU </a>";
    }
?>
```

Can somebody tell me what i did wrong and why its just display my blanked table with no values dispite the fact i search for vin which is actualy in database?

Comment: If you are seeing your table with just the header row, then  Hanky-웃-Panky's answer is correct.

Comment: I just did :) but it didnt change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `}` at the end of file with `Data` class.

You should always add at the beginning of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

to have displayed all errors.

**EDIT**

Other possible errors:

No database selected in PDO

and

```
$data = new Data;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );
...
```

`$usr` is not defined here, because object is `$data`

and of course this PHP code:

```
<?php
$data = new Data;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

if( $usr->fetchByVin() ) {
echo "Prebehne presmerovanie....";
} else {
echo "VIN nebolo nájdene";
}
}
}
else {
echo "Prosím prihláste sa <a href='login.php'> TU </a>";
}
?>
```

is not valid (too many closing `}`)

**EDIT2**

Please look at the following working code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');


define('DB_HOST', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');

class Data
{
    public $vin = null;

    public function __construct($data = array())
    {
        if (isset($data['vin'])) {
            $this->vin = stripslashes(strip_tags($data['vin']));
        }
    }

    public function storeFormValues($params)
    {
        $this->__construct($params);
    }

    public function fetchByVin()
    {
        $success = false;
        try {
            $con = new PDO(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_vin WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 1";

            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue("vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            $row = $stmt->fetch();


            if ($row === false) {
                return false;
            }

            $success = true;

            echo "<table>";
            echo "<th>Progress</th>";
            echo "<th>Claim number</th>";
            echo "<th>Make</th>";
            echo "<th>Status</th>";
            echo "<th>View</th>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>24</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['claim_number'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['licence'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['vin'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"detail.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "&action=detail\">detail</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        } catch (PDOExeption $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
        echo "</table>";
        return $success;
    }
}

?>


    <form method="post" action="">
        <p class="input_description">
            Search by VIN
        </p>

        <p class="input_field">
            <input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="vin">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="send">
        </div>
    </form>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $data = new Data;
    $data->storeFormValues($_POST);

    if ($data->fetchByVin()) {
        echo "Vin found - details above";
    } else {
        echo "VIN not found";
    }
}
?>
```

It removes all your errors as well as usage of `fetchColumn` method. This code is working good. However it's still not the best way to echo data by function and to return bool. You should rather return data and check in main file if data is different than false.

Comment: This won't always work, if the script can't be complied it won't work. You should set it manually in the php.ini file

Comment: I have a bit more code in this class and i didnt copy it here so thats the reason why i miss } but in real code its not missing. I have display_errors set on 1 and i get no error atm. :(

Comment: @MartinFerko Where do you select your database? I don't see database name in your code. Also you use `$data = new Data;` but later you use `$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );` and `$usr` is not defined. I've edited my answer a bit.

Comment: In file where i have form etc i have something like:
    include_once("config.php"); which looks like this:http://pastebin.com/DHzwMYkk

Comment: @MartinFerko I've also added working the whole working code to my answer.